# Step-by-step install on system with Win 7, but on different disk

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I have Ubuntu 14.04 on a bootable USB stick but decided against installing until I had decided I'm entirely sure of what I want to do.

I have three disks on my machine:

80G (Win 7 install)
3000G (Storage / software)
1000G (Old storage / software)

I want to format the latter one, and use for Ubuntu OS and software. But I'm not sure of what to do during the install process. The first two options talk about either installing alongside Win 7 on the same disk or removing it, so I have to go with the bottom option of doing a custom install.

But how do I make sure I format it correctly etc? I don't want to screw up.

Answer (score 0):

It's good to post it as a question before messing up with your partitions by selecting "Install alongside Windows" option.

- Boot from Ubuntu live disk and select Try Ubuntu option on startup.
- In Ubuntu 14.04, gparted utility is not preinstalled. So you have to install it manually by running the below commands on terminal(<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install gparted
  ```
- After the installation, open gparted partition editor from dash.
- Now resize(*shrink*) your `1000 G` Old storage partition to get the desired size for your Ubuntu partition.
- After resizing, an unallocated space would be created just below to your `1000 G` partition.
- Now create a new ext4 partition from that unallocated space.
- Run the Ubuntu installer and choose Something else option to install Ubuntu on the newly created ext4 partition.

Comment: Thanks. So: Is the live disk something alltogether different from my current install disk? Do I need two usb drives?

Comment: you doesn't need any two usb drives. Ubuntu live disk is your bootable Ubuntu USB(aka installation disk).

Comment: Okay so I'm in the partition editor now. I can't shrink that disk below 940189 MB. Should i have formatted it in Windows first?

Comment: no, post the gparted screenshot.

Comment: let us discuss here http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11833/room-for-avinash-raj-and-whoever-wants-to-make-company